# How to eliminate Cascade.ALL in a JPA Relation?

Tags: java, jpa, cascade, openjpa

I have a complex hierarchy between my entities. 
Because of an error(see below) i put in many places either CASCADE.ALL or CASCADE.PERSIST. From Top to bottom the annotations are ok. But from bottom to top, it is not what I want.

**It causes that the object are saved duplicate.**

How can I solve this issue??

P.S. Why I need relation between C and F: Because it is the standard way that I get the F Objects. (Currently %90 of Usecases)

[image: JPA Relationship between objects]

### ** Java Code -- Creating A-Tree **

```
   public A convertToA(final QueryAType aType, final A parent) {
        final A a = new A();

        if (parent != null) {
            a.setVater(parent);
        }

        final List<A> children = new ArrayList<A>();
        for (final QueryAType childPart : aType.getUnterbauteil()) {
            children.add(convertToA(childPart, a));
        }

        final List<B> bList = new ArrayList<B>();
        for (final QueryBType bType : aType.getBType()) {
            bList.add(convertToB(bType, a));
        }
        a.setBList(bList);
        a.setKinder(children);
        return a;
    }

    public B convertToB(final QueryBType bType, final A a) {
        final B b = new B();
        b.setA(a);

        final List<C> cList = new ArrayList<C>();
        for (final QueryCType cType : bType.getCType()) {
            cList.add(convertToC(cType, b));
        }
        b.setCList(cList);
        return b;
    }

    public C convertToC(final QueryCType cType, final B b) {
        final C c = new C();
        c.setB(b);

        final List<D> dList = new ArrayList<D>();
        for (final QueryDType dType : cType.getDType()) {
            dList.add(convertToD(dType, c));
        }
        c.setDList(dList);
        return c;
    }

    public D convertToD(final QueryDType dType, final C c) {
        final D d = new D();
        d.setProbe(c);

        final List<E> eList = new ArrayList<E>();
        for (final QueryEType eType : dType.getEType()) {
            eList.add(convertToE(eType, d, c));
        }

        d.setEList(eList);

        return d;
    }

    public E convertToE(final QueryEType eType, final D d, final C c) {
        final E e = new E();
        e.setD(d);

        final List<F> fList = new ArrayList<F>();
        for (final QueryFType fType : eType.getFType()) {
            fList.add(convertToF(fType, e, c));
        }
        e.setFList(fList);
        c.setFList(fList);
        return e;
    }

    public F convertToF(final QueryFType fType, final E e, final C c) {
        final F f = new F();
        f.setC(c);
        f.setE(e);

        final List<G> gList = new ArrayList<G>();
        for (final QueryGType gType : fType.getGType()) {
            gList.add(convertToG(gType, f));
        }
        f.setGList(gList);

        return f;
    }

    public G convertToG(final QueryGType gType, final F f) {
        final G g = new G();
        g.setMethode(f);
        return g;
    }
```

**Error without Cascade:**

---

org.apache.openjpa.persistence.InvalidStateException: Encountered unmanaged object "com.xxx.yyy.data.entity.E@18e0a217" in life cycle state unmanaged while cascading persistence via field "com.xxx.yyy.data.entity.F.e" during flush. However, this field does not allow cascade persist. You cannot flush unmanaged objects or graphs that have persistent associations to unmanaged objects. Suggested actions: a) Set the cascade attribute for this field to CascadeType.PERSIST or CascadeType.ALL (JPA annotations) or "persist" or "all" (JPA orm.xml), b) enable cascade-persist globally, c) manually persist the related field value prior to flushing. d) if the reference belongs to another context, allow reference to it by setting StoreContext.setAllowReferenceToSiblingContext(). FailedObject: com.xxx.yyy.data.entity.E@18e0a217

---

Comment: Are `c.f` and `e.f` a reference to the same entity or might both reference different instances?

Comment: @Thomas They are the same entities. The count of F Entities that you get from C and from all E Entities are equal.

Comment: The same entity doesn't mean they are the same instances.  Check that the F referenced by C == the F referenced by E.  How are you making the C managed (persist or merge)?

Comment: @Chris. They are the same instances

Comment: And how are C's, D's and E's managed?  Are you calling merge on an existing tree that was read in, are there new E instances etc.  More details are needed about the object tree, such as does it ever work?

Comment: @Chris C's,D's and E's managed with persist. I have object A in database and B persist with C, D, E, F, G. There a no new E instance. It does work with Cascade.All but the problem is that the objects are saved duplicated

Comment: Simplify your model to be sure - you should get the same behavior calling persist on a new C with a single new D, E and F instances in the tree, and it would be against the JPA spec so file a bug.  Chances are, one of the 3 references to F are referencing a different instance of the same entity - for instance did you also check that G references the same F instance that is referencing it?

Comment: @Chris I checked the references but there is only one instance of same entity. I included a code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure about this without digging deeper into the spec, but I guess this happens:

You assume the following: If F is persisted, the persist is cascaded via C and D to E.

OpenJPA, however, scans F and sees two relations: `F.c` and `F.e`. It cascades the persist to C but since `F.e` is not marked for cascading, OpenJPA doesn't know (yet) that E will be persisted as well (since it is not done processing F). Thus you get the error.

Adding a cascade to `F.e` and probably `E.d` as well should fix the problem.

*Edit:* Even if you first persist C (directly or via cascades), OpenJPA might try and process F before D. Thus, when `F.e` is processed, OpenJPA doesn't know that E will also be persisted (the cascade `D.e` has not been processed yet).

Another fix for this *might* be to rearrange the order of the associations within C. I say *might* since I don't know in which order OpenJPA processes the associations and cascaded, but to be honest, I'd not rely on any order. Thus, adding the cascade to `F.e` etc. seems to be the more robust option.

*Edit 2:*

For the duplicate persist problem, you might try and break the graph a bit.
Consider the owning sides: F owns the relation to C and E, E owns the relation to D and D owns the relation to C.

Thus, if you persist C, the cascade would include F which then should include E and D. D would be persisted anyways, hence you'd not need the cascade on `C.d`, which might cause the duplicates. I'd try and remove the cascades on `C.d` and `D.e`.

Comment: I already solved the the problem with adding the annotations but the problem is that the objects are saved duplicated

Comment: I removed the cascades on C.d and D.e. I got the same error again.

Comment: @Kayser which error, the duplicate? Did you add the cascade to `F.e`? At which entity are you starting the persist cascade?

Comment: I get the error "Error without Cascade". I start cascading by B

Comment: @Kayser The only possible error that I spotted in your code thus far might be `c.setFList(fList);`: As far as I understand your model there can be multiple Es for each C and thus you could have multiple lists of Fs. In this case, `c.setFList()` seems to replace the list with the Fs referenced by the current E and all references from the current C to its other Fs might be lost (which might influence the cascade depending on how you ended up with your annotations).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that problem is: If you persist F; entity E is persisted twice.

Before persisting entity F, setE() and setC() should be done in setters of entity F.